# db2: update multiple rows and field with a select on a different table

Tags: sql, db2

is it possible to increment the field a and b of a table (A.a and A.b) using the value c and d of a different table (B.c B.d) for all the row of A where A.x == B.z?

I'm getting crazy with this query

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DB2 and the SQL standard don't have a FROM clause in an UPDATE statement.
So you have to clearly separate the steps to

1. identify the rows to be modified and to
2. compute the new value.

.

Here is an example:

```
UPDATE TABLE A
SET A.FLD_SUPV = ( SELECT B.FLD_SUPV
FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B, TABLEC C,TABLED D
WHERE A.FLD1= B.FLD1
AND A.FLD_DT >= B.FLD_FM_DT
AND A.FLD_DT <= B.FLD_THRU_DT
AND A.FLD_DT > D.FLD_THRU_DT
AND A.FLD_DT < C.FLD_EFF_DT )
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT B.FLD_SUPV
FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B, TABLEC C,TABLED D
WHERE A.FLD1= B.FLD1
AND A.FLD_DT >= B.FLD_FM_DT
AND A.FLD_DT <= B.FLD_THRU_DT
AND A.FLD_DT > D.FLD_THRU_DT
AND A.FLD_DT < C.FLD_EFF_DT )
```

To update two fields you may use an example like this:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
 SET (col1, col2) = (
  SELECT col3, col4 
  FROM  table2 t2 
  WHERE t1.col8=t2.col9
 )
```

The optimizer will see that the sub-queries in the SET and the FROM clause
are identical and it should merge them in the internal execution plan.

Comment: so if I have two different field to update I have to do something like `update table A set A.a = (Select .. ), A.b = (select ...) where exists (....)` right?

Comment: I really need to use a single query, it's the point of my work

Comment: @Luka, for that you have to make like I said now in the answer :)

Comment: oh...what if I have to increment the second field col2 (in your example) of the result of the query. col1 += the result of the select

Comment: @Luka - please update your question with the revised requirement.  Also, please note that the second example here will only (be garuanteed to) work if either the two columns will accept `null`s, or the selection from `table2` will _always_ return a row.

Comment: where is `col3, col4` put `col3 + 1, col4 + 1`? but perhaps you should edit the question to the old one and make a new one. state examples of what you have and what you need.

Comment: I've solved my problem. now I was wondering how to make this question as much useful as possible for the other readers. not sure I' know what's the best..so if you have suggestion are more than welcome :)

Comment: When using this in my test environment it changed every row.. It was because the table being updated (in this example Table A) was included again in the sub-query, disconnecting the relationship to the set clause. Not sure if I am misunderstanding the original problem and this solution, but this was my experience using this  solution. Otherwise once I made the change and referred to the alias A declared outside of the sub-queries  it worked the way I expected updating matching rows. Just a reminder to always test queries in a test environment! Thanks for this solution, it otherwise helped me.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is possible. You can try something like this:

```
MERGE INTO A
USING (SELECT c, d, z from B) B
ON (A.x = B.z)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET A.a = A.a + B.c, A.b = A.b + B.d;
```

You can read more about MERGE [here](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/7608.merge-overview).

Answer (score 1):

Tested under DB2 10.6

Practically the same as @jhnwsk, but with added table short cuts.

```
Merge into "PRODUCTION"."COUNTRY" as N
      using (SELECT OD.NAME,OD.KEY from "DEVELOPMENT"."COUNTRY" as OD) as O
      on (O.KEY = N.KEY)
      WHEN MATCHED THEN
           UPDATE SET N.NAME=O.NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

This one also works quite good

`update TableA A 
set a = (select a from TableB B where A.x = B.z)
where exists
      (select 1 from TableB B where A.x = B.z) ;`

Answer (score -2):

```
UPDATE CS70P t1 
 SET (T1.TIPOCRE) = (
  SELECT MOROSO
  FROM  FCSALDOC t2 ,CS70P t1
  WHERE t1.NUMCRE =t2.CODCTA
 )
```