# DB2: Update query with several tables involved

Tags: database, db2

I have two tables, A and B. Both are related by a field. What I want to do is update a field of a subset of data from table B. This subset is filtered by a table A data. The data to be set is also taken from table B but from another different subset of data also filtered by another data from table A. Can this be done in DB2 using a direct query?

Thank you

Comment: Yes this can be done in DB2 using an UPDATE statement. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001022.html

Comment: Add some DDL and specifics of you filters, joins etc if you need help with actually writing the UPDATE

Comment: `MERGE` is also an option. You should be able to find examples around the web. Maybe this SO question for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478197/db2-update-multiple-rows-and-field-with-a-select-on-a-different-table